# Add and remove class on click with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
     <button class="fbutton btn pull-right filterevents " id="one" >School Events</button>
      <button class="fbutton btn pull-right filterevents" id="two" >Zone Events</button>
      <button class="fbutton btn pull-right filterevents" id="three" >My Events</button>
```

how to add class on every button when click

Comment: is this a demo?

Comment: Is this even a question?!

Comment: ... if the code is working, whats the issue? Did you mean to post this as an answer on someone else's question?

Comment: yes my friend i have share this code for use anyone else if needed

Comment: Answering your own question is fine, but please format it like a standard Stack Overflow post, and please ensure it hasn't already been answered (which this has, many times). You need to post a problem in question format and then the answer separately below. What you have right now is effectively a blog post with no context at all, hence why you've been downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for advise. i am  remember  your suggestion next time. Thanks Rory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".fbutton").click(function (e) {
$(this).addClass("fcurrent").siblings().removeClass("fcurrent");
});
```

Check Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/91/